# PHP : Help filtering Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I'm studying arrays in PHP and I would like to get just the three characters in my array. Here is an example of an array that I am currently working on :

"Array ( [0] => H [1] => e [2] => l [3] => l [4] => o [5] => [6] => F [7] => r [8] => i [9] => e [10] => n [11] => d )"

I would like to get the numbers 1,7 and 11 and echo it on my page.
Can anyone please help me?

I have tried some codes, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code :

$str = "Hello Friend";

```
        $arr1 = str_split($str);
        $arr2 = str_split($str, 3);
        foreach($arr1 as $arval){
            echo $arval;
        }
```

Comment: Why not just access the 3 elements independently?

Comment: Read any manual on php arrays.  https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php

    $str = "Hello Friend";

    $arr1 =  array(
      $str[1],
      $str[7],
      $str[11],
    );

    foreach($arr1 as $arval){
        echo $arval."<br>";
    }

?>
```

output:

```
e
r
d
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what you wish to do you can directly access the elements of the array at the indexes 1,7 and 11

```
$Hello_friend=array("H","e","l","l","o","F","r","i","e","n","d");
echo $Hello_friend[1];//echo index 1
echo $Hello_friend[7];//echo index 7
echo $Hello_friend[11];//echo index 11
```

You can directly access data from arrays by using the index that data is stored at in the form $array[index]

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic access:

```
 $arr1 = str_split($str);
        $arr2 = str_split($str, 3);
        foreach($arr1 as $key=>$arval){
          if($key==1 || $key==7 || $key==11){
            echo $key.PHP_EOL;
            echo $arval;
          }

        }
```

Direct access:

```
$val1= $arr1[1];
$val7= $arr1[7];
$val11= $arr1[11];
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the best way to use function , something like this ,
it's very easy and universal , can by used with any array and number of arguments.

```
function(){
   $num_arguments = func_num_args();
   $arg_list = func_get_args();
   for($i=0;$i<=$num_arguments;$i++){

       echo $GLOBALS['Hello'][$arg_list[$i]];
   }
}
```